# Python Selenium Webdriver TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

имеется список параметров, который подается на вход методу, в которой происходит парсинг.

Проблема в том, что в какой - то момент, при запуске очередной порции копии браузера, выкидывается ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/notebookcheck.net/notebookcheck.net.py", line 434, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/Git/notebookcheck.net/notebookcheck.net.py", line 424, in main
    for _ in executor.map(parse, list_index_game):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:/Git/notebookcheck.net/notebookcheck.net.py", line 288, in parse
    driver.get(url_main)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Я не пойму в чем причина.
Код:

```
def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_option.add_argument("headless")
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    try:
        # driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=chrome_option)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, chrome_options=chrome_option, service_args=service_args)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver
def parse(index_game):
    global count_add, count_no_add, gpus, gpu_list_norm, url_main
    print("Запуск браузера")
    driver = init_driver()
    print("Переход на страницу:", url_main)
    driver.get(url_main)
....

    driver.quit()
    #driver.close()


    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parse, list_index_game):
            pass
```

Comment: А долго эта страница грузится вообще
Что будет если бернуть в try -catch?

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    driver.get(url_main)
except TimeoutException:
    pass

Comment: @nick_gabpe да нет, не долго

Comment: а обёртывание  в try except помогло?